# Javascript function stringing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could anyone explain to me why the third alert function is simply not called?, and a possible reading resource in relation to the error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
   myFunction();
});

function myFunction()
{
    alert("First Function");

    mySecondFunction(function () {
        alert("Third Function");
    });
}

function mySecondFunction()
{
    alert("Second Function");
}
```

Comment: because you are not passing parameter to mySecondFunction

Comment: @SantoshJoshi he's passing a parameter, a function. He's just not executing it.

Comment: FYI `$( document ).ready(function() {
   myFunction();
});` in your case could be wrote `$(myFunction)`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, my bad, i mean to say he has not declared function to take any paramaters,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're doing nothing with that function in the parameter. You can do this:

```
function mySecondFunction(func)
{
    alert("Second Function");
    func();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing anonymous function `function () { alert("Third Function"); }` as a parameter to `mySecondFunction()`, but you're not calling this anonymous function anywhere inside `mySecondFunction()`.

This would work:

```
function mySecondFunction(callback)
{
    alert("Second Function");
    callback();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, you were spot on.